Non-Euclidean geometry: why constant curvature?
Non-Euclidean geometries are generally presented as models for the first four of Euclid's axioms, which do not satisfy the fifth axiom (parallel's postulate).
Most texts present two models of non-Euclidean geometries: hyperbolic geometry and spherical geometry.
These two models can be considered as instance of Riemannian manifolds of dimension 2 (surfaces), that are special in the sense that they have a constant curvature (negative in the case of hyperbolic geometry, positive in spherical geometry).
My question is: why do we only consider Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature. Why couldn't we have a model of non-Euclidean geometry which would be a surface of non-constant curvature?

Simplicity?  After all, disproving a conjecture only needs one counterexample.  But of course, you can consider non-constant examples as well.

@lulu since only these two models get mentioned in every sources I have read, I am wondering if (some interpretation of) the 4 first axioms do not apply in the non-constant case.

Nope, perfectly sensible geometries.  People look at Riemann Surfaces embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, for instance.  For genus $>1$ the underlying geometric surface can be given a metric with constant negative curvature, but the metric induced from the embedding can't have that property (fairly easy to see that an embedded surface must have a point of positive curvature somewhere).  Very interesting geometries.

Despite its name, "non-Euclidean geometry" is very much tied up to how Euclid did things. Its starting point is to discard the fifth postulate specifically, but keep everything else like Euclid would have done it, and then see what happens.
In particular, one thing Euclid did -- not often, but in a few fundamental places such as the proof of Proposition I.4, the SAS theorem -- is to say something like "imagine we move one triangle over so its one vertex covers the vertex in the other triangle". He has no explicit definitions or postulates that promise us this is something that makes sense, but he does so anyway. Depending on your temperament, we can consider this at best a hidden assumption, or at worst a proof by handwaving.
(See e.g. the commentary at http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI4.html)
This tacit assumption that we can move a geometric shape to any chosen place and orientation without stretching or tearing it, is also made in the classical development of non-Euclidean geometry. It is really a pretty strong homogeneity axiom, which effectively forces the plane to look sufficiently similar around different points that it ends up (from the anachronistic view of differential geometry) having constant curvature.

This is why one should read Hilbert or Birkhoff instead, they do not have unstated assumptions. And you do not need to assume homogeneity to prove constant curvature.

There is a way to read Euclid in which these kinds of unaxiomatized motions are found in more places than is usually acknowledged. Just as a very early example, Postulate 2 says any straight line segment can be extended in a straight line; that involves moving the given segment. Hartshorne's book briefly describes some post-Hilbert completions of Euclid's axioms in which rigid motions are axiomatized up front.
